# Does excel have an if statement equivelent? I can't get this program to work

Tags: excel, list, matching

The program has 5 columns.

> `Column A has item names
>   Column B has item sizes
>   Column C has item quantities
>   Column D has items that i need
>   Column E has the sizes for those items in the rows corresponding to the items`

Most items do not have multiple sizes, but for the ones that do, there will be multiple entries of that item in column A.

What I need to do is take all the items from column D and find them in column A and give me the corresponding quantity from C.

I have been using this code to achieve this. =INDEX(C:C,MATCH(D:D,A:A,0))
This works for all items besides the ones with multiple sizes. For these items it just spits back the first size number every time. 
Would there be a way to match A and D, and then check if there is a value in the size column, if so, give out the correct number?

I see how my wording is confusing here is an example of what I mean.

```
apples          5lb bag           12            apples       10lb bag
apples         10lb bag           13            
bananas                            5            grapes
grapes                             7
```

Which using the is line of code "=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(D:D,A:A,0)) " would result in giving me the correct "7" for the grapes, but for the apples, it would give me the first result it comes across, which is the 12.

How would I get it to check the other columns to give me the 13 for apples?

Comment: If yopu are looking to sum the qty then sumif or sumifs. If not then I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you looking for a [multiple criteria Index/Match](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/)?

Comment: Even if you are trying to return one, and the two column list is unique, SUMIFS is you answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then this will get you the correct number:

```
=IF(E2<>"",SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,D2,B:B,E2),SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,D2))
```

[image]